# how to write ObjectNode code to below json data?

Tags: json

I want to generate a response like below. How can I do it using `ObjectNode` and `ObjectMapper`? In java class I have to write a coding for below response:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "time": "2016-05-27T11:15:36+10:00",
    "data": {
        "result": {
            "addresses": {
                "addressId": "180056310",
                "addressSummaryType": "PrimaryAddressSummary",
                "addressType": "Property Address with Number",
                "status": "Confirmed",
                "number": "6",
                "numberTo": "8",
                "streetName": "REGENT",
                "streetType": "Street",
                "locality": "WOLLONGONG",
                "postcode": "2500",
                "state": "NSW",
                "addressType": "RM",
                "subAddresses": {
                    `entercodehere`
                }
            },
            "serviceLocation": {
                "readForServiceDate": "2013-09-27",
                "locationId": "LOC000136215004",
                "customerServiceAreaId": "CSA200000010939",
                "exchangeServiceArea": "WLGG",
                "facsRealm": "74",
                "latitude": "-34:25:25.7",
                "longitude": "150:53:27.3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a POJO to represent the response, with the appropriate field names and types, annotate the fields with `@JsonProperty` and use the `writeValueAsString` method of the `ObjectMapper` class to serialize the POJO to a JSON string.